# Eject additional blank space from top of label to home position

Tags: printing, zpl

Currently, My label prints up to a point such that when the user goes to tear the label at its perforation, they are tearing about 1/16 of the label off.

What specific command must be declared to specify to the printer to eject the media to the absolute next perforation in the media?

[image: LP2844 showing similar symptom.]

This image shows how my printer currently stops printing. The model in question is a TLP 2844-Z.

I have tried using ^PH but that will provide an additional label instead of to the next perforation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **^LH** to set the label origin, **^LT** for shifting the Label Top and I use the **^LS** for shifting the label left or right.

For example, where "..." are other label setup commands.

```
^XA . . . ^LH0,0^LT30^LS6
```

Also, with the Zebra TLP2844, if you open it up, move the label stock, and close it again (e.g. when replacing labels), it may need to be reset to align the tear-off.  To reset the tear-off, when already powered up, hold the green button until it flashes 4 times, then release.  The printer will then reset its stock handling to properly align the tear-off.  You may want to do this reset BEFORE experimenting with the label positioning commands to make sure you have a clean start position.

Also, be aware of the Suppress Backfeed Command **^XB**.

Comment: It's now printing to the end of the data provided in the label, but not adjusting the perforation. One thing to look out for, **^XB** This was causing the issue and was hidden in with the setup commands. Thanks!

Comment: I think I edited my answer while you were commenting.  Use the 4-flashes reset to re-align the tear-off position anytime after opening the printer up; or if code experiments scramble things.